# SQL select not a string doesn't return NULL value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given the following table and data

```
CREATE TABLE #temps
(
    id int,
    name varchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO #temps VALUES (1, 'foo')
INSERT INTO #temps VALUES (2, '')
INSERT INTO #temps VALUES (3, NULL)
```

I want to select all rows that don't have `foo` in the `name` column.

```
SELECT * FROM #temps
WHERE name <> 'foo'

DROP TABLE #temps
```

Why does this return only row #2? The name in row #3 is NOT `foo` and should be returned.

Comment: Why is there a hash tag in your table name? I've never seen that before, is it legal or is there something I don't?

Comment: The `#` before the table name denotes a temp table. Search "temporary table" in this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution would be

```
SELECT * FROM #temps
WHERE ISNULL(name, '') <> 'foo'
```

Answer (score 5):

> Why does this return only row #2? The
>   name in row #3 is NOT foo and should
>   be returned.

Others have answered what to do about it. As to why it is like that, `null` represents an **unknown** value. The value for column `name` in row 3 **could** be `foo`. We don't know that because the value is unknown.

The `where` clause have to evaluate to `true` to return a row. `name <> 'foo'` is not `true` and it is not `false` it is unknown.

Answer (score 4):

You need `where Name <> 'foo' or Name is null`.
Null can't be compared for equality.